# Can I make a method in my controller which return nothing just call a java method from a service class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I'm new and inexperienced in spring boot but I need to make a webapp from my well workin desktop codes, what I want to have an index page, which is a JSP, where should be a button which can be clickable, but it doesn't lead an other JSP view, just call a method in my controller which call a java method that will do something. My other objective to have a form on that index page where the user can write stuff and by clicking a button, this stuff will pass to the controller method to pass it a java method to use it.

Is it possible? And how can I code it? what annotations I need it to my controller method and how can I say in index JSP to do that method in my controller?

Comment: Too broad kind of a question to answer. If you google definitely you can find tutorials for it.

Comment: Controllers are meant to handle HTTP requests and therefore require a HTTP response. You could just send an empty 200 response after performing the API call.

Comment: Refer to tutorials online in good websites for spring boot like https://www.baeldung.com/. Refer mvc tutorials like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-tutorial

Comment: The most important to call a java service method by clicking a button on page, that method not necessary be called by a controller method, but as I know I cannot call a java method directly from JSP.

Comment: I think this is exactly what you are looking for https://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-web-application-with-spring-boot.